# React-select how to render only option values that are not undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to render my `Option` values based on `if/else` that will show only `option` related to parameter from query

```
const renderLsit = useMemo(() => {
    return mediaCategories?.Entities?.map((category, _) => {
      if (
        category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Other &&
        params.type === "categories"
      ) {
        return {
          value: category.CategoryId,
          label: category.CategoryName,
          index: category.CategoryId,
        };
      } else if (
        category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Main &&
        params.type === "genre"
      ) {
        return {
          value: category.CategoryId,
          label: category.CategoryName,
          index: category.CategoryId,
        };
      }
    });
  }, [params, mediaCategories.Entities]);
```

But `renderList` contains `undefined` values after map and this is braking react-select. So it is returning something like this:
[image]
this is for `else if` and my `Entities` list dose not have `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do a `.filter()` before `.map()`

```js
return mediaCategories?.Entities?.filter(c => c !== undefined /*or whatever you want filter on*/).map((category, _) => {
      if (
        category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Other &&
        params.type === "categories"
      ) {
        return {
          value: category.CategoryId,
          label: category.CategoryName,
          index: category.CategoryId,
        };
      } else if (
        category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Main &&
        params.type === "genre"
      ) {
        return {
          value: category.CategoryId,
          label: category.CategoryName,
          index: category.CategoryId,
        };
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks gi=ot it working. but in any other ase your answer is right :)

Answer (score 0):

add filter before mapping to fillter out nulish values

```
 mediaCategories?.Entities?.filter(Boolean).map((category, _) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more idiomatic / ES6 way:

```js
const renderList = useMemo(() => {
    return mediaCategories?.Entities?.filter(
        ({ CategoryTypeCode }) =>
            (CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Other &&
                params.type === "categories") ||
            (CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Main &&
                params.type === "genre")
    ).map((category) => ({
        value: category.CategoryId,
        label: category.CategoryName,
        index: category.CategoryId,
    }));
}, [params, mediaCategories.Entities]);
```